# Is it possible to add a margin between each row in a bootsrap V4 striped table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, margin

Is it possible to separate each row using a margin, in a striped table in bootstrap v4. I want each row to spaced out a little to be more readable.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Username</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">1</th>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">2</th>
  <td>Jacob</td>
  <td>Thornton</td>
  <td>@fat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">3</th>
  <td>Larry</td>
  <td>the Bird</td>
  <td>@twitter</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried .table tr {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

Comment: And what happened? Would `.table tr th, .table tr td { padding-bottom: 10px; }` achieve the desired result?

Comment: Padding doesn't provide a gap in between each row.

Comment: Inside a table there cannot be any space that is not "part of the table" - which seems to be what you want. As long as the table resides on a solid colored background, you might be able to achieve the desired result using borders.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a play around tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table rows does not have margin values. You may consider to use padding values to `td`.

For reference :

```
.table td{
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: My desired goal is a gap between each row. not just space with no gap.

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of what you trying to achieve .